# ASP.NET Service - Web or Windows?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, windows-services

I'm looking for a method in which an application I will be hosting will have the ability to run a tasks on a giving interval of x minutes to check a database and send out reminder emails automatically. This would of course be based upon a scenario in which someone has scheduled a meeting, let's say, on a day and the service's job would be to send a reminder a week prior to the meeting and on the day of the meeting. Would I be looking to run a Windows Service to complete this function or is there a better way to do such a thing? Not asking for full source just a push in the right direction. Thanks for the guidance in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like a windows service would work good here.  Set a timer in the service that will read your database at the given interval and perform the actions you want.
Here's a [link](http://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/2173801/Creating-a-Windows-Service-in-NET.htm) that might help you to get started.